# JSON Array Parse Error

Tags: arrays, json

JSON editor shows error on line 5. But is not everything okay for my JSON?

My JSON file:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "result": [
        "data_x": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 12.00
        }],
        "data_y": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 36.50
        }],
        "data_z": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 88.50
        }]
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend using the JSON Linter in the future (https://jsonlint.com). This should find all kinds of pesky syntax errors.

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 5:
...esult": [  "data_x": [{   "date": "201
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

I get this error.

Comment: Your JSON is wrong. `"result"` is declared as an array, but on the next line, you're using the map syntax (`"name":"value"`)

Answer (score 0):

Missing curly brackets in **result** array.

**It should be like below:**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "result": [{
        "data_x": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 12.00
        }],
        "data_y": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 36.50
        }],
        "data_z": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 88.50
        }]
    }]
}
```

Validated on [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Thanks, my problem is resolved. The array state in the array is a complex situation

Answer (score 0):

"result" is an array (`[]`) and you are defining properties within as if it was an object (`{}`).

You may want to make it an object:

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "errorMessage":"",
   "result":{
      "data_x":[
         {
            "date":"2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value":12.00
         }
      ],
      "data_y":[
         {
            "date":"2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value":36.50
         }
      ],
      "data_z":[
         {
            "date":"2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value":88.50
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Or, if you want to keep the array, you can do as [imEnCoded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7377521/imencoded) [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51043725/7625902):

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "errorMessage": "",
    "result": [{
        "data_x": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 12.00
        }],
        "data_y": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 36.50
        }],
        "data_z": [{
            "date": "2018-03-09T05:17:08",
            "value": 88.50
        }]
    }]
}
```